# Different friend workflows for different URLs

Tags: clojure, oauth-2.0

I'm building a web app that will authenticate users with standard username/password pair, but will also need to authorize access to Dropbox and/or Google Drive to do some background file processing.

I'm using [friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) to log users in. I wanted to use [friend-oauth2](https://github.com/ddellacosta/friend-oauth2) but I don't know how to have different `friend` workflows for different URLs.

What I would like to have is:

1. `/users/*` protected with `workflows/interactive-form`
2. `/dropbox/*` and `/gdrive/*` protected with `oauth2/workflow`
3. Any other URL public

I know how to do points 1 and 3 (with `friend/authenticate` and `friend/authorize`) but I have no clue how to get #2. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap your routes separately with different middleware definitions.  Here is an example using compojure for route definitions:

```
(defroutes interactive-routes*
  ; Put your interactive routes here
  ; ...
  )
(defroutes oauth-routes*
  ; Put your oauth routes here
  ; ...
  )

(def interactive-routes
  (-> #'interactive-routes*
    (friend/authenticate {:credential-fn (partial creds/bcrypt-credential-fn users)
                          :workflows [(workflows/interactive-form)]})
  ))
(def oauth-routes
  (-> #'oauth-routes*
    (friend/authenticate {:credential-fn (partial creds/bcrypt-credential-fn users)
                          :workflows [(oauth2/workflow)]})
  ))

(defroutes all-routes
  (ANY "*" [] interactive-routes)
  (ANY "*" [] oauth-routes)

; Then do what you normally would with `all-routes` (e.g., wrap with more middleware, pass to ring server)
```

(Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10822337/4020885) for the notes on different middleware for different routes)